# Using URL (Link) withing ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a ViewBag in my View like this:

```
ViewBag.Text = "This is the" + @Html.ActionLink("link","action","Home");
```

and it doesn't work. Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: What is not working? what is your expected behavior ?

Comment: I would like to have a working url, but instead it shows as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Html.Raw` method.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Text = "This is the" + @Html.ActionLink("link", "Index", "Home");
}

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Text)
```

If you simply use `@ViewBag.Text`, razor will render something like

```
This is the<a href="/home/index">link</a>
```

Because razor will html encode the expression result when it is prefixed with `@`

`Html.Raw` method will return the markup without Html encoding.